# How to rename files within subfolders in my working directory using Command Prompt

Tags: for-loop, recursion, rename, subdirectory

Context: I'm trying to streamline grading 194 student assignments, as it's a bit tedious as is. I have about 194 subfolders (one for each student, named automatically with ID numbers) in a parent folder, each with a single assignment inside (sometimes .docx, sometimes .pdf). My goal is to get all of those files into a single folder together without losing track of where they originally came from. The hitch is that the files themselves are named by the students who submitted them and I have a bunch of duplicate names (30 "Assignmnet1", 15 "Untitled(1)", etc., so the files need to be renamed in order to be identifiable. So what I'm really stuck on is how to ask the system to cycle through the directory from the parent folder, read the file names within, and rename them to match the name of the subfolders they're inside.

I was able to use the following code to generate a txt file containing the directories of each assignment:

For /R G:\RR1_renaming\ %G IN (*) do Echo "%G" > for /l %a in (1,1,194) do (>>%a.txt

...which I copied into Excel to streamline writing the renaming section of code, like this:

ren "Homework01.docx" "IDnumber_Student01.docx"
ren "Homework01.docx" "IDnumber_Student02.docx"
ren "Homework01.pdf" "IDnumber_Student03.pdf"  etc.

Since I've had some luck with {For /R G:\RR1_renaming\ %G IN (*) do Echo "%G"} at successfully ratcheting through the subfolders, I keep trying to use it with the rename command, but haven't had any luck.  Some things I've tried:

For /R G:\RR1_renaming\ %G IN (*) do ren ...
For /R G:\RR1_renaming\ %G IN (*) do Echo "%G" > ren ...
For /R G:\RR1_renaming\ %G IN (*) ren...
For /R G:\RR1_renaming\ %G IN (*) > ren...   and so on

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of merging all files into one folder? You seem to have OCD about structure. Yet there is already an existing folder structure.

Comment: it would help if you tell us which tool you want to (or can) use to accomplish the goal. is that powershell or something?

Comment: I'm using Windows Command Prompt (CMD), though I guess I'm open to other ways to accomplish the same thing.  I've been able to make the most progress using CMD thus far.  I want them all in one folder for several reasons, one of which being that I have R script that requires them all to be in a single folder.

Answer (score 1):

I did eventually figure this out for anyone who may have the same issue.  It may not be a single line of code, but it's what I could figure out by myself and still saves me a ton of time when I use it.

To rename a single file with the name of its folder:

```
cd subfoldername & ren "fileinsubfolder.pdf" "subfoldername.pdf" & cd..
```

Run this in the parent folder.  It's actually 3 commands stitched together with "&".  "cd" tells it to change directory to subfolder "subfoldername", then "ren" renames the file, then "cd.." changes the directory back to the parent folder (1 step forward in the directory tree, action, 1 step back in the directory tree).

To rename all files within every subfolder, I used Excel to create a separate line for each command, then copied into Command Prompt and ran them all at once.  To get a list of each directory for every file that I could copy into Excel, I used:

```
For /R G:\Parent_Folder\ %G IN (*) do Echo "%G" > for /l %a in (1,1,200) do (>>DIRECTORIES.txt
```

The above creates a TXT document within the parent folder called "DIRECTORIES.txt" and contains the full directories of every individual file within every subfolder.  I believe the "200" in the "for /l" loop "(1,1,200)" can be changed to accommodate the amount of files you have (500 if you have 500 files, etc.).  "G:\Parent_Folder" is the entire parent directory.

I originally got the tip to use Excel from this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znhqGrF4gVQ